# toggle class on hover and on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, height, toggle

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4v01t46/)

I have a click function (item) that shows 'item-overlay' but i'd like to also add a hover to preview the div 'item-overlay' by 100px I added a mouseenter and mouseleave with height to my current code but this then works on click ?! this is my click function -

```
     }).on('click', '.item', function (e) {
    (".item click");
    if ($(this).closest('.timelineTile').hasClass("clicked")) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).siblings('.item-overlay').slideToggle('fast');


    }
```

and an example of what i tried to do -

```
    }).on("mouseenter", ".item", function(e) {
    if ($(this).closest('.timelineTile').hasClass("clicked")) {
    e.stopPropagation();
     $(this).siblings('.item-overlay').height(100); }

    }).on("mouseleave", ".item", function(e) {
     if ($(this).closest('.timelineTile').hasClass("clicked")) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).siblings('.item-overlay').height(0); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your other open/close animations use `hide` and `show`, which also alter the `display` style.

Try this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w4v01t46/3/

```
}).on("mouseenter", ".item", function (e) {
    if ($(this).closest('.timelineTile').hasClass("clicked")) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).siblings('.item-overlay').css({display: "block"}).height(100);
    }
}).on("mouseleave", ".item", function (e) {
    if ($(this).closest('.timelineTile').hasClass("clicked")) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).siblings('.item-overlay').hide().height('');
    }
});
```

**notes:**

- `height('')` will reset the height css to inherit (i.e no value).

If you want the height reset when you click again set it with the `slideToggle` call:

```
}).on('click', '.item', function (e) {
    (".item click");
    if ($(this).closest('.timelineTile').hasClass("clicked")) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).siblings('.item-overlay').height('').slideToggle('fast');
    }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w4v01t46/5/

Comment: this then adds the height (100px) again on click :( really can't figure out how to do this!

Comment: Updated to clear the height on click. To get best results first time you need to provide a clear description *of the intended behavior*, rather than what you think is the specific bug :)

Comment: thats great thank you the only thing is when you click it does a toggle first then you have to click again to show the full div and then if you move your mouse away it goes all together :S

Comment: I charge £60 an hour if you want me to do all the work for you :) Just check your clicked class/flag etc in the mouseleave.